# How do I make a MKAnnotationView touch sensitive?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I currently have a map view with some annotation on it. I have the annotation with custom images. The problem I am trying to fix is the sensitivity of the images. When I try to drag them, it feels like I have to touch the exact center for it to be focused on. Is there a way to make the touch bounds bigger?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To do this, you need to subclass `MKAnnotationView` to create your own custom `MKAnnotationView`. In your subclass, override the following functions:

```
- (BOOL)pointInside:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent*)event
{
    // Return YES if the point is inside an area you want to be touchable
}

- (UIView*)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent*)event
{
    // Return the deepest view that the point is inside of.
}
```

This allows interactive views (such as buttons, etc.) to be pressed. The default implementation in `MKAnnotationView` is not strict on `pointInside` and `hitTest` because it allows presses that are actually inside one annotation to get sent to a different annotation. It does this by figuring out the closest annotation center to the touch-point and sending the events to that annotation, this is so that close-together (overlapping) annotations don't block each other from being selected. However, in your case you probably want to block other annotations if the user is to select and drag the topmost annotation, so the above method is probably what you want, or else it will set you on the right path.

**EDIT:**
I was asked in comments for an example implementation of `hitTest:withEvent:` - This depends on exactly what you are trying to achieve. The original question suggested touching and dragging images within the annotation whereas in my case I have some buttons inside the annotation that I want to be interactive. Here's my code:

```
- (UIView*)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent*)event
{
    UIView* hitView = [super hitTest:point withEvent:event];
    if (hitView != nil)
    {
        // ensure that the callout appears above all other views
        [self.superview bringSubviewToFront:self];

        // we tapped inside the callout
        if (CGRectContainsPoint(self.resultView.callButton.frame, point))
        {
            hitView = self.resultView.callButton;
        }
        else if (CGRectContainsPoint(self.resultView.addButton.frame, point))
        {
            hitView = self.resultView.addButton;
        }
        else
        {
            hitView = self.resultView.viewDetailsButton;
        }
        [self preventSelectionChange];
    }
    return hitView;
}
```

As you can see it's quite simple - The `MKAnnotationView` implementation (called as `super` on the first line of my implementation) only returns the first (outermost) view, it does not drill down through the view hierarchy to see which sub-view the touch is actually inside. In my case I just check if the touch is inside one of three buttons and return those. In other circumstances you may have simple rectangle-based drilling down through the hierarchy or more complex hit tests for example to avoid transparent areas within your view to allow touches to pass through those parts. If you do need to drill down, `CGRectContainsPoint` can be used the same way I have used it, but remember to offset your points into local view coordinates for each view-level you drill into.

The `preventSelectionChange` method is to prevent my custom annotation from becoming selected, I am using it as a customisable/interactive callout from map pins and this keeps the pin it relates to selected instead of allowing the selection to change to this annotation.

Comment: Could you implement hitTest method please ?

Comment: If I could up vote your answer again I would! Thanks for the update.

Comment: Hi again, how about pointInside:withEvent: ? Is this where you propose CGRectContainsPoint be implemented ?

Comment: @Daniel Yes, you could if you like use the same implementation for both methods in order to determine if the point should be considered 'inside' your annotation or not. However, pointInside:withEvent is likely to be much more simple and just return YES if the point is inside your outermost view rectangle. The only time you'd need to return NO is when you have transparent areas that should be considered 'outside' your view, even though they fall within the bounding rectangle.

Comment: I can receive touch down events on my button, but touch up inside doesn't trigger, the map view seems to capture this and deals with deselecting the annotation. Any thoughts ?

Comment: Implement both methods and they should be consistent - i.e. if pointInside returns YES then hitTest should return a valid view. If pointInside returns NO then I don't think hitTest is even called. Also, you may want to prevent deselection because annotations by default allow other annotations that are behind to be selected.

Comment: Not for me! example plz.

Answer (score 1):

Did you subclass MKAnnotationView or did you change the just set the image property of it?

Here's the documentation for setting the image property.

> Discussion:
>   Assigning a new image to this property also changes the size of the view’s frame so that it matches the width and height of the new image. The position of the view’s frame does not change.

Check the size of the frame of your annotation view, which is where your object can receive touches.

Answer (score 0):

I implemented something similar in the following manner

1. Create a subclass of the Gesture Recognizer class that handles touches
2. Create a subclass of the UIImage class, this class uses the recognizer class to handle your gestures
3. Use this in the annotation

The gesture recognizer subclass will handle your gestures if you perform them at any point in the image. This should help you.

Keep us updated on whether this solution worked for u...

Answer (score 0):

@jhabbott solution never worked for me, as I mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45997984/127493).

I have an image and a label side by side. The image was shown by setting annotationview `image` property, and the label by adding an `UILabel`

I redirected the `func point(inside:with:)` method to the `UILabel` one (which included the image zone) and `hitTest` did return exactly the same view whether I clicked on the label or the image. But label click did not produce any callback...

Finally, I ended up by enlarging the MKAnnotationView frame to enclose label + image, I set `annotationView.image` to `nil`, and I created my custom `UIImageView`.

Because I wanted the anchor point at the middle of the image, I had to set a custom one :

```
self.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 
self.myLabel.frame.width, height: self.myLabel.frame.height)
self.centerOffset = CGPoint(x: self.frame.width/2, y: self.myImageView.frame.height/2)
```

Then I deleted `point(inside:with:)` and `hitTest(point:with:)` overrides that did nothing.

And now, for the first time, my annotation view is completely reactive.