# Prevent touch propagation to annotation beneath

Tags: iphone, ios, touch, mkmapview, mkannotationview

I have a custom `MKAnnotationView`. In its `setselected:animated` method I'm adding to it a custom  bubble loaded from a nib, adjust the annotationview's frame to include this view and redraw the annotation circle with other color, like this (first - not selected , second - selected, blue - frame, green - custom bubble view with alpha = 0.8, red - the annotationview):

### [image]

It works fine, the bubble appears, and can be "closed" only by tapping outside of it (this is why I've increased the frame). I have some buttons on this bubble and they are clickable if there is nothing under the annotation just the map.

BUT when under the callout bubble there is another annotation I can click "through"  the entire bubble. When I tap on one of the buttons, the tap highlight appears, but an other annotation gets selected because the `didSelectAnnotationView` fires ...

I tried to make the bubble opaque/semitransparent, no luck;  set exclusiveTouch on buttons, on the view itself, no luck; tried not to mess with frame, still can click through. 
Am I missing something ?

Thanks

**Edit** : **Shorter: Why can I click through a `UIView` added in `addSubview` in an MKAnnotationView if there is other MKAnnotaionView under this UIView ?**

Details :

```
- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
  if(selected)
  {
    initialFrame = self.frame;       // save frame and offset to restore when deselected
    initialOffset = self.centerOffset;  // frame is correct for a circle, like {{2.35, 1.47}, {12, 12}}

    if (!self.customCallout) 
    {
      self.customCallout = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCallout" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
    }
    // adjust annotationview's frame and center
    // callout is 200x120, here frame is {{2.35, 1.47}, {200, 132}} 
    self.customCallout.layer.cornerRadius=5;
    self.customCallout.exclusiveTouch = YES;
    [self addSubview:self.customCallout];
  }
...
}
```

`initWithAnnotation` has these :

```
   self.canShowCallout = NO;  // to appear the subview
   self.exclusiveTouch = YES; // ...
   self.enabled = YES;
   self.opaque = YES;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default behavior of the touch handling methods (touchesBegan: touchesEnded: etc.) have this note in the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIResponder/touchesBegan%3awithEvent%3a):

> The default implementation of this method does nothing. However immediate UIKit subclasses of UIResponder, particularly UIView, forward the message up the responder chain.

MKAnnotationView is a subclass of UIVIew.  As a result, when your annotation gets a touch, it is passing it to it's super class and on up the responder chain, so eventually you map view gets the touch and activates the covered annotation.

To resolve, implement the touch handling methods in your annotationView class, and do not pass the touch events up the responder chain.

Comment: This means I should implement the touches.. methods and shouldn't call [super touches..] ?

Comment: Eventually, this helped me a lot and finally resolved the problem, thanks :). Also, I found this description which could help others struggling with these stupid annotations : [link](http://heath-tech.blogspot.com/2012/02/ios-50-mkmapview-mapkit-mapview-edge.html) Could you add this link also to your answer, maybe it will help others too.

Comment: I tried this on iOS 5.1 and it didn't work for me.  Double Tapping on the MkAnnotationView goes straight to the map view underneath.

Comment: Is you annotation returning YES for [annotation canBecomeFirstResponder]?  Default behavior is to return NO, so you would have to override this for the annotation to be in the responder chain and able to receive the touches.

Answer (score 0):

can u check which event fire first

```
1, the button on bubble
2, didSelectAnnotationView
```

if the button on bubble fire first
you can intersect the touch in bubble by subclassing the

```
touchesBegan:touches
touchesMove:touches
touchesEnd:touches
```

in bubble view to preventing the propagation

Comment: The didSelectAnnotationView fires first... I've even enabled the highlight for the button to see if it's touched. The highlight appears, but right after that the didSelectAnnotationView fires and the button's action is not executed after that ... Probably it's some internal, undocumented handling stuff ...

Comment: try to adding 

    [super setSelected: selected animated: animated];

on your last line of setSelected method in your MKAnnotationView subclass

Comment: Same result ... Must be some internal annotation handling issue, I've tried nearly everything, even rewriting the class from scratch...

Answer (score 0):

I think you will find the following links very useful:

http://blog.asynchrony.com/2010/09/building-custom-map-annotation-callouts-part-2/

[How do I make a MKAnnotationView touch sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8648263/how-do-i-make-a-mkannotationview-touch-sensitive)

The first link discusses (among other things) how to prevent the propagation and the second one how to detect the touches.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue recently, spending way to much time that I did not have. Solving it, actually ended up being quite straightforward, of course only realizing such after spending ages.

You'll simply want to subclass your MapView, and within that subclass to the following:

```
override func gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    debugPrint(gestureRecognizer)
    if gestureRecognizer is UITapGestureRecognizer {
        return true
    } else {
    return false
    }
}
```

The reason being, that all the handling of map interaction, such as zooming panning etc, seems to be handled internally, and not accessible to us. The gestures causing us problems is however accessible, but for my case, I only want the tap gesture that handles selecting and deselecting of an annotation.