# When I set customized annotation view's frame, view disappears until pinch the map

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mkannotationview

I customized my MKAnnotationView, when I touch it, it enter following code

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view {
    CellThumbnailView *thumbnailView = (CellThumbnailView *)view;

    [mapView setCenterCoordinate:thumbnailView.thumbnail.coordinate animated:YES];

    CGSize size = [thumbnailView.thumbnail getThumbnailSize];

    thumbnailView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height);
    thumbnailView.centerOffset = CGPointMake(0, -[thumbnailView.thumbnail getThumbnailCenterOffset] + size.height / 2);

    // Center map at annotation point
    thumbnailView.imageView.center = CGPointMake(size.width / 2, size.height/ 2);
    thumbnailView.imageView.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height);
    thumbnailView.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[thumbnailView.thumbnail getPopupImageName]];

    CGSize labelOffset = [thumbnailView.thumbnail getThumbnailLabelOffset];
    thumbnailView.titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 45, 20)];
    thumbnailView.titleLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    thumbnailView.titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    thumbnailView.titleLabel.shadowColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:1 alpha:0.5];
    thumbnailView.titleLabel.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, -1);
    thumbnailView.titleLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:17];
    thumbnailView.titleLabel.alpha = 1;
    thumbnailView.titleLabel.minimumScaleFactor = .8f;
    thumbnailView.titleLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
    thumbnailView.titleLabel.center = CGPointMake(thumbnailView.center.x - labelOffset.width, thumbnailView.center.y - labelOffset.height);
    thumbnailView.titleLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%dG", thumbnailView.thumbnail.traffic];
    [thumbnailView addSubview:thumbnailView.titleLabel];

    self.location.text = thumbnailView.thumbnail.desc;
    self.traffic.text = thumbnailView.titleLabel.text;
    self.reportView.hidden = NO;
}
```

If you notice this:

```
thumbnailView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height);
```

It means I want to change my thumbnail to a big one, so I changed frame.
But with this frame change, when I touch the view, it disappears.
But after I zoom it in or out, it shows again.

The strange thing is: when I remove that frame change, the problem is gone.

I want to know why and how to solve this problem (I still need change frame if possible).

Comment: did you get any solutions? 
facing the same issue in swift  3 ios 9+ . using autolayout.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a call to `[thumbnailView layoutSubviews]` after you change the frame? I had a similar problem where my views were just disappearing after the frame change until the map was touched/zoomed/whatever. This was the missing link to get autolayout to do its magic.

**Update** 
Actually, this may have been a red herring. What seemed to definitively work for me was to manipulate the `centerOffset` property of the MKAnnotationView rather than its `frame` directly. Doing things to `frame` led to weird effects where the origin got "reset" momentarily to `0,0` and only got back to normal when the map was touched. In the end, I used `centerOffset`, adjusted the frames of subviews instead, and used [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8649951/2199136) of hittesting to get interaction in the subviews to work.

Answer (score 0):

This did the trick for me

```
CGSize size = [self customSize];

if (!CGSizeEqualToSize(size, self.frame.size))
{
    [self setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height)];
}
```

setting the frame once for all solved any issue, building for iOS7 does't show this problem.