# Custom MKAnnotationView touch zone is ridiculously narrow

Tags: ios, mapkit, mkannotationview

My custom `MKAnnotationView` subclass do not set it's `image` property. Instead, it handle some subviews to be displayed.

I implement `public func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView)` in my delegate to detect annotation touch.

Because touch zone is by default calculated with the `image` property, my annotation view touch zone is about 1px large. This is ridiculous.

This is how I create it:

```
init(annotation: JZStreamAnnotation) {
    self.imageView = UIImageView.init(image: <an image>)
    self.imageView.contentMode = .center
    super.init(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: JZStreamAnnotationView.identifier)
    self.canShowCallout = false
    self.imageView.center = CGPoint(x: self.frame.width/2, y: self.frame.height/2)
    self.addSubview(self.imageView)
}
```

[I read this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8649951/127493), but I cannot figure out how the hitTest method works. Here an implementation that make nothing:

```
override func hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {
    if point.x > -100, point.x < 100, point.y > -100, point.y < 100 {
        //return self
        //return self.imageView
        return super.hitTest(point, with: event)
    }
    return .none
}
```

A breapoint  located in the `if` clause fires, but returning whatever (`super` / `self` / `imageView`) does nothing.

Lastly, if I implement hitTest like this:

```
override func hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {
    return .none
}
```

and if I clic on my annotationView exact center, the `public func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView)` delegate method if fired!

Any advice to enlarge the touch zone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understood, `func point(inside:with:)` and `hitTest(point:with:)` do not help to enlarge the zone which call the delegate `public func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView)`

Finally, I ended up by enlarging the MKAnnotationView frame to enclose my annotation subviews and moving the anchor point to be exactly where I wanted my annotation center

```
self.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 
self.myLabel.frame.width, height: self.myLabel.frame.height)
self.centerOffset = CGPoint(x: self.frame.width/2, y: self.myImageView.frame.height/2)
```

Then I deleted `point(inside:with:)` and `hitTest(point:with:)` overrides that did nothing.

That's the only way I succeeded to make my annotation view fully reactive.